# Reconciliation tool [comparing two large data set of records]

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, ignite

I have been asked to build a reconciliation tool which could compare two large datasets (We may assume input source as two excels).

Each row in excel contains 40-50 columns and record to be compared at each column level. Each file contains close to 3 million of records or roughly 4-5 GB of data.[data may not be in sorted format]

I would appreciate if i could get some hint.
Can following technologies be a good fit

1. Apache Spark
2. Apache Spark + Ignite [assuming real time reconciliation in between time frames]
3. Apache Ignite + Apache Hadoop
4. Any suggestion to build out in-house tool.

Comment: can you please elaborate the comparing means.

Comment: for example 2 large csv comparison which says each line matched ,mismatched for each line and prepare a report for that isnt it? If so you can use spark  rdd load (using sc.textfile) 2 files in to 2 rdds and compare in a simple way

Comment: @@Ram thanks for answering, In addition to this we also need to produce a report which fields doesn't match in a record. Report should be in following format:  1. Left Miss (i.e. csv1 records missing from right) 2. Right miss (i.e. CSV2 records are missing from csv1) 3. if records are available in both csv file (records have unique identifier say a primary key in  a table) which fields doesn't match.

Comment: It's a kind of normal query but we don't want to run on oracle database. We are exploring ignite at the moment (+ (ignite + hadoop)).

Answer (score 0):

I have also been working on the same-

You can load the csv files to temporary tables using Pyspark/Scala and query on top of the temp tables created.

Answer (score 0):

First a Warning:

Writing a reconciliation tool contains lots of small annoyances and edge cases like date formats, number formats (commas in numbers, scientific notation etc), compound keys, thresholds, ignoring columns , ignoring headers/footers etc etc.

If you only have one file to rec with well defined inputs then consider doing it yourself.

However, if you are likely to try to extend it to be more generic then pay for an existing solution if you can because it will be cheaper in the long run.

Potential Solution:

The difficulty with a distributed process is how you match the keys in unsorted files.

The issue with running it all in a single process is memory.

The approach I took for a commercial rec tool was to save the CSV to tables in h2 and use SQL to do the diff.

H2 is much faster than Oracle for something like this.

If your data is well structured you can take advantage of the ability of h2 to load directly from CSV and if you save the result in a table you can also write the output to CSV too or you can use other Frameworks to write a more structured output or stream the result to a web page.

If your format is xls(x) and not CSV you should do a performance test of the various libraries to read the file as there are huge differences when  dealing with that size.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on the above problem and here is the solution.
https://github.com/tharun026/SparkDataReconciler
The prerequisites as of now are

1. Both datasets should have the same number of columns
2. For now, the solution accepts only PARQUETS.

The tool gives you match percentage for each column, so you could understand which transformation went wrong.